# Can't Produce PubNub data stream to Kafka Cluster

Tags: java, apache-kafka, pubnub

I am currently trying to pass live streaming data from PubNub to a Kafka cluster.
I am able to get the data from PubNub but when I try to produce to Kafka, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Subscription Manager Consumer Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.propsToMap(KafkaProducer.java:1238)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:298)
```

This occurs as soon as the Kafka cluster is initialized. I've looked around but there isn't much information on this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What does your creation of `KafkaProducer` look like?

Comment: Looking further into this to see if we can find the root cause

Comment: You may consider using the official PubNub Kafka Bridge - https://github.com/pubnub/kafka-bridge

It's written in Rust and runs in Docker.   There is a quick start in 60 seconds or less by running: https://github.com/pubnub/kafka-bridge#part-1-up-and-running-in-60-seconds---kafka-zookeeper-and-sample-feed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Produce PubNub data stream to Kafka Cluster

There is an official approach to bridging [Kafka Topics to PubNub Channels](https://github.com/pubnub/kafka-bridge).  Using Docker.

Here is the test example that should get you up and running in 60 seconds. Start the docker compose file in a terminal window. This will launch Kafka, Zookeeper and a sample feed generator on the topic topic.

For security, you will need to get your private API keys from: https://dashboard.pubnub.com/signup The following API Keys are for public-use and may be rotated.

Open a new terminal session and run the following commands:

> In the following command, notice `KAFKA_TOPIC=topic` is the Kafka Destination Topic and `PUBNUB_CHANNEL=channel` is the PubNub Source Channel.

```sh
cd kafka-bridge
docker build -f kafka/plain/dockerfile -t kafka-bridge .
docker run                                                                        \
    --network=host                                                                \
    ## ~ Replace with your own API Keys ~ https://dashboard.pubnub.com/signup     \
    -e PUBNUB_PUBLISH_KEY=pub-c-6b57a39e-79e7-4d1d-926e-5c376a4cb021              \
    -e PUBNUB_SUBSCRIBE_KEY=sub-c-df3799ee-704b-11e9-8724-8269f6864ada            \
    -e PUBNUB_SECRET_KEY=sec-c-YWY3NzE0NTYtZTBkMS00YjJjLTgxZDQtN2YzOTY0NWNkNGVk   \
    ## ~ Replace with your own API Keys ~ https://dashboard.pubnub.com/signup     \
    -e PUBNUB_CHANNEL_ROOT=''                                                     \
    -e PUBNUB_CHANNEL='channel'                                                   \
    -e KAFKA_GROUP=test-group                                                     \
    -e KAFKA_TOPIC=topic                                                          \
    -e KAFKA_BROKERS=0.0.0.0:9094                                                 \
    kafka-bridge
```

[image: PubNub Kafka]

Answer (score 0):

To update for anyone who comes across this question, PubNub now has a feature specifically designed to stream data from PubNub to Kafka:

1. Create an [Events & Actions](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/serverless/events-and-actions/overview) [listener](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/serverless/events-and-actions/events) to define which events you are interested in, for example, a message is published to a particular channel
2. Create a [Kafka Action](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/serverless/events-and-actions/actions/create-kafka-action) and provide your Kafka endpoint and configuration